# Access to stdout_lines when using Ansible

Tags: debugging, ansible

Given I have "registered" files in directory using shell task in a var `sonarqube_plugins_installed`, when I "debug" this using

```
- name: Debug
  debug:
    var: sonarqube_plugins_installed.results
```

I see for example

```
TASK [sonarqube : Debug] ************************************************************************
ok: [sonarqube] => {
    "sonarqube_plugins_installed.results": [
        {
            "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
            "changed": true, 
            "cmd": "ls  /opt/sonarqube/sonarqube-6.7/extensions/plugins/sonar-build-breaker-plugin-*.jar", 
            "delta": "0:00:00.003748", 
            "end": "2019-09-18 04:04:54.355667", 
            "failed": false, 
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "_raw_params": "ls  /opt/sonarqube/sonarqube-6.7/extensions/plugins/sonar-build-breaker-plugin-*.jar", 
                    "_uses_shell": true, 
                    "argv": null, 
                    "chdir": null, 
                    "creates": null, 
                    "executable": null, 
                    "removes": null, 
                    "stdin": null, 
                    "stdin_add_newline": true, 
                    "strip_empty_ends": true, 
                    "warn": true
                }
            }, 
            "item": "build_breaker", 
            "rc": 0, 
            "start": "2019-09-18 04:04:54.351919", 
            "stderr": "", 
            "stderr_lines": [], 
            "stdout": "/opt/sonarqube/sonarqube-6.7/extensions/plugins/sonar-build-breaker-plugin-2.2.jar", 
            "stdout_lines": [
                "/opt/sonarqube/sonarqube-6.7/extensions/plugins/sonar-build-breaker-plugin-2.2.jar"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I access for example `stdout` in another task? In another task I want to process each item in `results` using `with_items` and output `stdout`.

How can this be done?

Comment: What about sonarqube_plugins_installed.results[0].stdout ?

Comment: @itiic this would only get `stdout` for the first element in the list. Although the example list only has one element, OP indicated he want to process each item in `results`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should be a good start:

```
- name: show stdout for each result
  debug:
    var: item.stdout
  loop: "{{ sonarqube_plugins_installed.results }}"
```

As you guessed, this is going trough each elements in your `results` list.

An other approach if your want to print all lines at once would be to process the data structure through [`json_query`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) with the relevant [jmespath](http://jmespath.org/examples.html) expression to only extract the needed information

```
- name: show sdtout list for all results
  debug:
    msg: "{{ sonarqube_plugins_installed | json_query('results[].stdout[]') }}"
```

You could also combine the two and loop over the simple list of stdouts only

```
- name: show stdout for each result
  debug:
    var: item
  loop: "{{ sonarqube_plugins_installed | json_query('results[].stdout[]') }}"
```

You could also use the [`map`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#map) filter to extract the desired attribute:

```
- name: show stdout list of all results
  debug:
    msg: "{{ sonarqube_plugins_installed.results | map(attribute='stdout') | list }}"
```

And there other solutions you can use that I'm sure you will find in the [specific ansible filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html) and [general jinja2 filters](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#list-of-builtin-filters) documentations